# Codeigniter Insert Batch is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

my function is :

```
function saveproduct($p_arrProductInfo,$p_arrProductLangInfo){
        $this->db->trans_start();       
        $this->db->insert_batch('t_product', $p_arrProductInfo);    
        $this->db->insert_batch('t_productlang', $p_arrProductLangInfo); 
        $this->db->trans_complete();    
}
```

Myerror is :

```
INSERT INTO t_productlang (a_active, a_availablefororder, a_categorydefaultid, a_condition, a_createdby, a_createddate, a_ean13, a_ecotax, a_manufacturerid, a_onlineonly, a_onsale, a_price, a_productid, a_quantity, a_reference, a_showprice, a_styleguideurl, a_supplierid, a_upc, a_weight, a_wholesaleprice, a_createdby, a_createddate, a_description, a_descriptionshort, a_lang, a_linkrewrite, a_metadescription, a_metakeywords, a_metatitle, a_name, a_productid, a_shopid, a_tags) VALUES ('1','2013-03-28 07:10:24','&lt;p&gt;With a contemporary approach to the latest fashion trends, &lt;strong&gt;People&lt;/strong&gt; is a brand that gives a completely modern spin to ethnic wear for women.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This &lt;strong&gt;3/4 sleeved, printed, short kurta&lt;/strong&gt; boasts of a &lt;strong&gt;printed yoke&lt;/strong&gt; and a &lt;strong&gt;pleated front&lt;/strong&gt;. Pair it with a fitted churidar for a style statement that will definitely make heads turn wherever you go. Buy online now!&lt;/p&gt;','Featuring People&amp;#39;s Ethnic, All-over print Short Kurta with a Band Collar, 3/4th sleeve and . It comes in Regular Fit. Wash as indicated on label.','1','printed-band-collar-kurta','Buy PEOPLE Dupatta &amp; Kurta for women at Trendin.com - Shop online for Printed Band Collar Kurta for women at best price with Free Shipping &amp; 15 days Exchange policy','printed band collar kurta, women kurta, women dupatta, buy kurta online, buy dupatta online, kurta dupatta online shop, buy kurta for women, kurtis online, online kutis for sale, trendin','PEOPLE Kurta &amp; Dupatta Online -Printed Band Collar Kurtaat Trendin.com','Printed Band Collar Kurta',3629,'1',''), ('1','2013-03-28 07:10:24','&lt;p&gt;With a contemporary approach to the latest fashion trends, &lt;strong&gt;People&lt;/strong&gt; is a brand that gives a completely modern spin to ethnic wear for women.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This &lt;strong&gt;3/4 sleeved, printed, short kurta&lt;/strong&gt; boasts of a &lt;strong&gt;printed yoke&lt;/strong&gt; and a &lt;strong&gt;pleated front&lt;/strong&gt;. Pair it with a fitted churidar for a style statement that will definitely make heads turn wherever you go. Buy online now!&lt;/p&gt;','Featuring People&amp;#39;s Ethnic, All-over print Short Kurta with a Band Collar, 3/4th sleeve and . It comes in Regular Fit. Wash as indicated on label.','1','printed-band-collar-kurta','Buy PEOPLE Dupatta &amp; Kurta for women at Trendin.com - Shop online for Printed Band Collar Kurta for women at best price with Free Shipping &amp; 15 days Exchange policy','printed band collar kurta, women kurta, women dupatta, buy kurta online, buy dupatta online, kurta dupatta online shop, buy kurta for women, kurtis online, online kutis for sale, trendin','PEOPLE Kurta &amp; Dupatta Online -Printed Band Collar Kurtaat Trendin.com','Printed Band Collar Kurta',3629,'2',''), ('1','2013-03-28 07:10:24','&lt;p&gt;With a contemporary approach to the latest fashion trends, &lt;strong&gt;People&lt;/strong&gt; is a brand that gives a completely modern spin to ethnic wear for women.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This &lt;strong&gt;3/4 sleeved, printed, short kurta&lt;/strong&gt; boasts of a &lt;strong&gt;printed yoke&lt;/strong&gt; and a &lt;strong&gt;pleated front&lt;/strong&gt;. Pair it with a fitted churidar for a style statement that will definitely make heads turn wherever you go. Buy online now!&lt;/p&gt;','Featuring People&amp;#39;s Ethnic, All-over print Short Kurta with a Band Collar, 3/4th sleeve and . It comes in Regular Fit. Wash as indicated on label.','1','printed-band-collar-kurta','Buy PEOPLE Dupatta &amp; Kurta for women at Trendin.com - Shop online for Printed Band Collar Kurta for women at best price with Free Shipping &amp; 15 days Exchange policy','printed band collar kurta, women kurta, women dupatta, buy kurta online, buy dupatta online, kurta dupatta online shop, buy kurta for women, kurtis online, online kutis for sale, trendin','PEOPLE Kurta &amp; Dupatta Online -Printed Band Collar Kurtaat Trendin.com','Printed Band Collar Kurta',3629,'3',''), ('1','2013-03-28 07:10:24','&lt;p&gt;With a contemporary approach to the latest fashion trends, &lt;strong&gt;People&lt;/strong&gt; is a brand that gives a completely modern spin to ethnic wear for women.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This &lt;strong&gt;3/4 sleeved, printed, short kurta&lt;/strong&gt; boasts of a &lt;strong&gt;printed yoke&lt;/strong&gt; and a &lt;strong&gt;pleated front&lt;/strong&gt;. Pair it with a fitted churidar for a style statement that will definitely make heads turn wherever you go. Buy online now!&lt;/p&gt;','Featuring People&amp;#39;s Ethnic, All-over print Short Kurta with a Band Collar, 3/4th sleeve and . It comes in Regular Fit. Wash as indicated on label.','1','printed-band-collar-kurta','Buy PEOPLE Dupatta &amp; Kurta for women at Trendin.com - Shop online for Printed Band Collar Kurta for women at best price with Free Shipping &amp; 15 days Exchange policy','printed band collar kurta, women kurta, women dupatta, buy kurta online, buy dupatta online, kurta dupatta online shop, buy kurta for women, kurtis online, online kutis for sale, trendin','PEOPLE Kurta &amp; Dupatta Online -Printed Band Collar Kurtaat Trendin.com','Printed Band Collar Kurta',3629,'4',''), ('1','2013-03-28 07:10:24','&lt;p&gt;With a contemporary approach to the latest fashion trends, &lt;strong&gt;People&lt;/strong&gt; is a brand that gives a completely modern spin to ethnic wear for women.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This &lt;strong&gt;3/4 sleeved, printed, short kurta&lt;/strong&gt; boasts of a &lt;strong&gt;printed yoke&lt;/strong&gt; and a &lt;strong&gt;pleated front&lt;/strong&gt;. Pair it with a fitted churidar for a style statement that will definitely make heads turn wherever you go. Buy online now!&lt;/p&gt;','Featuring People&amp;#39;s Ethnic, All-over print Short Kurta with a Band Collar, 3/4th sleeve and . It comes in Regular Fit. Wash as indicated on label.','1','printed-band-collar-kurta','Buy PEOPLE Dupatta &amp; Kurta for women at Trendin.com - Shop online for Printed Band Collar Kurta for women at best price with Free Shipping &amp; 15 days Exchange policy','printed band collar kurta, women kurta, women dupatta, buy kurta online, buy dupatta online, kurta dupatta online shop, buy kurta for women, kurtis online, online kutis for sale, trendin','PEOPLE Kurta &amp; Dupatta Online -Printed Band Collar Kurtaat Trendin.com','Printed Band Collar Kurta',3629,'5',''), ('1','2013-03-28 07:10:24','&lt;p&gt;With a contemporary approach to the latest fashion trends, &lt;strong&gt;People&lt;/strong&gt; is a brand that gives a completely modern spin to ethnic wear for women.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;This &lt;strong&gt;3/4 sleeved, printed, short kurta&lt;/strong&gt; boasts of a &lt;strong&gt;printed yoke&lt;/strong&gt; and a &lt;strong&gt;pleated front&lt;/strong&gt;. Pair it with a fitted churidar for a style statement that will definitely make heads turn wherever you go. Buy online now!&lt;/p&gt;','Featuring People&amp;#39;s Ethnic, All-over print Short Kurta with a Band Collar, 3/4th sleeve and . It comes in Regular Fit. Wash as indicated on label.','1','printed-band-collar-kurta','Buy PEOPLE Dupatta &amp; Kurta for women at Trendin.com - Shop online for Printed Band Collar Kurta for women at best price with Free Shipping &amp; 15 days Exchange policy','printed band collar kurta, women kurta, women dupatta, buy kurta online, buy dupatta online, kurta dupatta online shop, buy kurta for women, kurtis online, online kutis for sale, trendin','PEOPLE Kurta &amp; Dupatta Online -Printed Band Collar Kurtaat Trendin.com','Printed Band Collar Kurta',3629,'6','')
```

Actually the first and second arr keys and values are getting merged in the transaction
it shows A Database Error Occurred

```
   Error Number: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: The error means that you are not inserting the correct number of values according to the number of fields.

Comment: Does it work without executing it under transaction?

Comment: note the problem occurs when executing for t_productlang, can u print_r($p_arrProductLangInfo) under saveproduct() and see what it contains and comment all other statements. we are actually debuuging.

Comment: I am responding to Angelin Nadar: No it does not work without the transaction. At least in my test it not worked.

Answer (score 1):

So simple, the error clear says it.

I saw your query for record 1 it has mentioned 34 columns and given only 27 columns-values. there is mismatch.

Comment: Actually the first table and second table is getting merge the productlang table has 13 fields but t_product table has more both is getting merge in the excution of the transaction